# Can I send an email using a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver

is that possible to send an email using broadcast receiver ?as let say when some action happen i need to send an email automatically example when it become mid night i need the system to send an email is that possible ??

i know that i can send the mail email using the intent action but what i need is at this specific time the system send the email.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses);   
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, carbonCopies);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);        
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");   
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
```

if anyone can help me with my question i will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

> as let say when some action happen i need to send an email automatically example when i become midnight i need the system to send an email is that possible ?

Not using that code, because that is for the *user* to send the email. It displays a UI; it does not send the email.

You are welcome to use JavaMail or something to send an email, but you will need account credentials for the mail server. Given that, you can then use `AlarmManager`, coupled with `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, to send the email at midnight.

Comment: is there any example or tutorial to follow it ?? and how to use these three JavaMail, mail server,  AlarmManager ??? i am new to the email app

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will helpful for you. Thanks

[How to Send Email in Android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/)